# How to import artifact from one subproject into another in multimodule project?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, multi-module

Collegues, i have subproject `utils` in my multimodule project. The pom looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.comp.kort</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>utils</artifactId>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${project.build.sourceJdk}</source>
                    <target>${project.build.targetJdk}</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I run command `mvn clean install` and `utils-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` is created in the local maven repository.

After that i add next dependency into pom of another subproject

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.comp.kort</groupId>
            <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

But when i add `import com.comp.kort` to classes of my second subproject i receive `Can't resolve symbol 'kort'`.

What should i to import com.comp.kort in the second subproject correctly?

`mvn dependency:tree` on my second subproject shows:

```
[INFO] com.comp.kort:kort-sp-integration:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ibm.jbatch:com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.batch:javax.batch-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] \- com.comp.kort:utils:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

Comment: The way you present your question here, you make it appear like you're attempting to import a package which is impossible in Java. Did you mean to `import com.comp.kort.*` ?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, i can't import `com.comp.kort.*`

Comment: You should fix mistakes in the question rather than confirm in comments. In any case two more things: 1) are there actually classes in the package com.comp.kort inside the util module? 2) what is shown when you execute `mvn dependency:tree` in your subproject?

Comment: As you can see the utils jar is in the dependencies of the project, so it is not a maven problem. I can only guess there are no classes in the package you're using.

Answer (score -2):

It seems `<scope>provided</scope>` is not right, and you can remove it.

> Provided is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

You can see [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Comment: Removed, but it didn't help.

Comment: provided is indeed wrong, but it doesn't cause this problem.

Comment: @Gimby Maybe I misunderstood the question, but provided scope cause indeed that submodule'classes cannot be resolved when they are imported.

Comment: At runtime, not at compile time. At compile time provided dependencies are available. As you can see in the dependency:tree output.

Comment: @Gimby It's not completely correct. For example, one project has 3 modules(A,B,C). Module B depend A and module C depend B. If module A's scope is provided, it's available in module B as you said, but it will be not available in module C.